# Upload de imagem react-native com axios e multer, backend com nodeJS

Tags: node.js, react-native, file-upload, axios, multer

Eu preciso fazer o upload de uma imagem pro backend e salvar ela, mas a função da api não realiza nada

**Função que chama o axios**

```
  const teste = () =>{


console.log(picture)

Axios.post(apiPath+'/api/addPostagem', 
  

  {picture: picture}, // se botar apenas "picture" aki sem os {} não consegue chamar a api(da 
  //network error)
  {
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${picture._boundary}`,
    }
  }
  
  ).then((response)=> {
    console.log(response.data)

  });
}
```

**Pegando a foto com o expo-image-Picker**

```
 async function imagePickerCall() {
if (Constants.platform.ios) {
  const { status } = await 
 Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

  if (status !== "granted") {
    alert("Nós precisamos dessa permissão.");
    return;
  }
}
const data = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 1,
});
//console.log(data);
if (data.cancelled) {
  return;
}

if (!data.uri) {
  return;
}

setPicturePreview(data.uri) // colocando a foto selecionada numa 
variável pra mostrar na tela atual

const newUpload = new FormData(); //adicionando informações da imagem em 
//um formData

newUpload.append("picture", data);

setPicture(newUpload);
}
```

**no console.log(picture) retorna o objeto da imagem que peguei com o image picker e se eu usar esse 'uri' pra mostrar a imagem na pagina atual funciona normal**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**No backend**

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'img/'}) // é pra salvar a imagem numa pasta que esta no mesmo 
//nivel do codigo

app.post("/api/addPostagem",upload.single("picture"), (req, res) =>{
console.log(req.picture+'1') // retorna undefined
console.log(req.file+'2') // retorna undefined


res.send('123') // o front end recebe isso, porem a imagem n é salva
})
```

**no backend também já tentei usar o multer assim, porem da o mesmo resultado:**

```
const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination(req, file, callback) {
  callback(null, 'img/')
},
filename(req, file, callback) {
  callback(null, file.originalname + Date.now());
},
})
 const upload = multer({ 
  storage: Storage,
  
  limits:  2 * 1024 * 1024
})
app.post("/api/addPostagem",upload.single("picture"), (req, res) =>{
console.log(req.picture+'1') // retorna undefined
console.log(req.file+'2') // retorna undefined


res.send('123') // o front end recebe isso, porem a imagem n é salva
})
```

Comment: Como é o objeto `picture`? Ele é um `FormData`?

Comment: sim, ele é esse print ai

Comment: ok, mas como voce montou esse `FormData`? como está o `append(...)`

Comment: editei o post colocando o uso do imagePicker/ como fiz o picture

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, pelo que eu entendi, pro multer reconhecer a imagem, tem q ter no formData 3 caracteristicas, nome, type e uri, como o piker q to usando n fornece o nome e o type, eu crio um quando crio o formData

**Criando o formData**

```
...
setPicturePreview(data.uri) // 
let typeImg = (data.uri).slice(-3); // pegando as 3 ultimas letra pra pegar o tipo

const newUpload = new FormData(); //adicionando informações da imagem em um 
formData
newUpload.append("picture",
{
  name: 'postagemPicture',
  type: 'image/'+typeImg,
  uri: data.uri
}
...
```